# While loop with try/catch causes endless loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

The code snippet below causes an endless loop, when I enter a character. That's really weird for me, for a wrong number it works fine, but when I am entering any character, it causes an endless loop.

```
boolean checkValue = false;

Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!checkValue) {

System.out.println("Enter 1, 2 or 3");      

    try {
            input = console.nextInt();

       switch (input) {
            case 1:
                // code 
                checkValue = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                 // code 
                checkValue = true;
                break;
            case 3:
               // code 
                checkValue =  true;
                break;

            default: // when entered a wrong number
                System.err.println("Wrong Input"); 
                checkValue = false;
        }
        }

            catch(Exception e) { // when entered a character

                System.err.println("Wrong Input"); 
                checkValue = false;

            } 
   }
```

Comment: You don't update the value of auswahl, there's your problem.

Comment: What for the God sake is auswahl??

Comment: I mean it 'll go straight to the next iteration,without breaking out of it.

Comment: sorry, i missed to translate all in english auswahl = input. changed the code.

Comment: Cause you will get NumberFormatException when you enter a character and it will go on catch clause. By me it's strange that you are entering in the infinite loop because when you go into catch clause, the program should exit.

Comment: @drgPP and how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Instead of trying to catch an exception, check for the right format beforehand. If it is not an integer, you still need to consume the input. See my answer below.

Comment: @Dennis and mine too ;). Yes the only pb is to consume the "bad" input in the catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the right type of the input, instead of trying to catch an exception. When you find the wrong input has been supplied, you have to consume the input in order to proceed to the next try. Like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean checkValue = false;
    int input;

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!checkValue) {

        System.out.println("Enter 1, 2 or 3");      

        // Check if we have an integer
        if (console.hasNextInt()) {
            input = console.nextInt();

            switch (input) {
            case 1:
                // code 
                checkValue = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                // code 
                checkValue = true;
                break;
            case 3:
                // code 
                checkValue =  true;
                break;

            default: // when entered a wrong number
                System.err.println("Wrong Input"); 
                checkValue = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            // when entered a character
            System.err.println("Wrong Input");
            // Consume the wrong input.
            console.next();
            checkValue = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this this improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You assign the input into one variable :

```
        input = console.nextInt();
```

But the switch statement tests a different variable :

```
   switch (auswahl) {
```

EDIT :

Add `console.nextLine()` to your exception handler, to consume the end of the current line, to allow the next `nextInt` to read from the next line.

Comment: sorry, missed to translate everything auswahl is the german word for input. but the problem still exists.

Comment: @Panther add `console.nextLine()` to your exception handler, to consume the end of the current line.

Answer (score 1):

What's "auswha1" ? Its value is not updated and your scanner is outside the loop.
Moreover, are you sure that you are testing a character in your switch ? It looks like an int.

Edit : 
Instantiate a new scanner before calling nextInt, it should work :

```
try {
     Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
     int input = console.nextInt();
     switch (input) {
         ...
```

Comment: sorry, missed to translate everything auswahl is the german word for input. but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `console.nextInt()`, you will read only integers on the input. Then, when you enter something which is not an int, you catch an Exception. There you need to *consume* the bad input, e.g. with a `nextLine()`:

```
        catch(Exception e) { // when entered a character
            System.err.println("Wrong Input"); 
            checkValue = false;
            console.nextLine(); // <=== add
        }
```

Then it works...

Answer (score 0):

auswahl variable is not assigned with your input. Actually speaking this variable is not even in scene till you use it in switch.

```
boolean checkValue = false;
        int input;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (!checkValue) {

        System.out.println("Enter 1, 2 or 3");      

            try {
                    input = console.nextInt();

               switch (input) {
                    case 1:
                        // code 
                        checkValue = true;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                         // code 
                        checkValue = true;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                       // code 
                        checkValue =  true;
                        break;

                    default: // when entered a wrong number
                        System.err.println("Wrong Input"); 
                        checkValue = false;
                }
                }

                    catch(Exception e) { // when entered a character

                        System.err.println("Wrong Input"); 
                        checkValue = false;

                    }
            System.out.println("Program Ends");
```

Comment: sorry, missed to translate everything auswahl is the german word for input. but the problem still exists.

Comment: Even I am very new to StackOverflow. Do a thorough research and analysis before posting questions like this. You won't be appreciated here if you post silly things like this. I do understand even you are new here but keep this in mind and all the best. Cheers @Panther

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean checkValue = true;

Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
while (checkValue) {

System.out.println("Enter 1, 2 or 3");      

    try {
            input = console.nextInt();

       switch (input) {
            case 1:
                // code 
                checkValue = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                 // code 
                checkValue = false;
                break;
            case 3:
               // code 
                checkValue =  false;
                break;

            default: // when entered a wrong number
                System.err.println("Wrong Input"); 
                checkValue = false;
        }
        }

            catch(Exception e) { // when entered a character

                System.err.println("Wrong Input"); 
                checkValue = false;

            } 
   }
```

Comment: the "right" condition is on right input. Try and tell me whether it works. I edited the exit condition after right input.

Answer (score 0):

You probably get `java.util.InputMismatchException` after inputting any illegal character. It does not clear the input buffer, so calling nextInt() causes the same error etc. 
Add console.next(); to the catch clause to skip the wrong character.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
catch (Exception e) { // when entered a character

            System.err.println("Wrong Input");
            checkValue = false;
            console = new Scanner(System.in);//Edit

}
```

Comment: the loop should not break, the user should have another try to enter a correct input.